# How to update all links in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, hyperlink, .net

I have a hyperlink: http:\some-domain.ca.com and I need to update it to http:\new-domain.pa.com

How do I globally update every single occurrence on the entire Sharepoint site?

I will accept answers for front-end or back-end (bonus for both).

I was thinking of maybe someway to checkout every single file, open it in explorer view, then run a script on that directory of files, but I don't think I can access that explorer view in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good practice, but for the front end site, you could add some javascript code on your master page, such as:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
        // set the old base URL of your site, and the new ones
        var oldBaseUrl = 'http://yoursite.com';
        var newBaseUrl = 'http://yournewsite.com';

        // get old URL, and replace the old base url with new one
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr(href);
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace(oldBaseUrl, newBaseUrl);

        // set the new URL to the link
        $(this).attr('href', newUrl);
    });
});
```

Backend looks like a better option. You could change the site collection URL via SharePoint Management Shell. Have a look at [this](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/07/how-to-change-site-collection-url.html) article.

Comment: Wouldn't that only apply for the homepage? Unless I added that to every directory which isn't an option

Comment: You could add that to the masterpage, will of course will be applied to the entire site.